# Show post updated date instead of published

Tags: date, post-meta

I need simple solution to show updated date instead of published without adding any functions. I have read few articles, but they are bit complex using "dirty" code. This is my current code is it possible to modify this code to show updated date:

```
    $date = sprintf( '<span>' . __( 'Posted', 'theme' ) . ' <a href="%3$s"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time></a></span>',
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( time_ago() ),
    esc_html( get_day_link( get_the_date('Y'), get_the_date('m'), get_the_date('d') ) )
  );
```

I have tried with `get_the_modified_date`, but this did not produce updated date:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_date/

Thanks!

Comment: And what have it produced? Could you show your code with get_the_modified_date?

Comment: I have just replaced get_the_date with get_the_modified_date.

Comment: Could you show that code exactly? It's hard to say what is wrong with code that you can't see ;)

Comment: Even with my limited PHP knowledge I can see that this updated code can't work. No point of sharing it.

Comment: As explained in comment above: I have just replaced get_the_date with get_the_modified_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_the_modified_date should do what you're looking for. I am guessing that perhaps you are struggling a bit with the sprintf syntax.

```
 $date = sprintf( '<span>' . __( 'Posted', 'theme' ) . ' <a href="%3$s"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time></a></span>',
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( time_ago() ),
    esc_html( get_day_link( get_the_date('Y'), get_the_date('m'), get_the_date('d') ) )
  );
```

Let's break it down:

## sprintf argument 1 - the string with placeholders

`sprintf( '<span>' . __( 'Posted', 'theme' ) . ' <a href="%3$s"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time></a></span>',`

This is the main string that will be built. It has 3 placeholders. However, they are in a non-traditional order.

1. The link (`<a href=%3$s`) has a placeholder for variable #3, a string.
2. The datetime attribute (`datetime=%1$s`), which is part of the HTML time element that makes the time machine-readable (useful for advanced features, and if the time element contains more than just the actual time), has a placeholder for variable #1, a string.
3. And finally the displayed time (`>%2$s</time>`) is looking for variable #2, a string.

## sprintf arguments 2,3, and 4 - the values

Those 3 variables are provided in the following function arguments (again, not in the order they are used):

```
esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
esc_html( time_ago() ),
esc_html( get_day_link( get_the_date('Y'), get_the_date('m'), get_the_date('d') ) )
```

The **first**, which is feeding into that datetime= attribute, is getting the post's published date and outputting it in the 'c' format, which is a standard date format that looks like    20019-03-27T15:19:21+00:00.

The **second**, which is the displayed time, is referencing a function I don't recognized, called time_ago().

The **third**, which is being used for the link href=, is generating the link based off of the post's published date.

So, to properly change the date and still use that function, we should adjust all 3 parameters.

```
$date = sprintf( '<span>' . __( 'Posted', 'theme' ) . ' <a href="%3$s"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time></a></span>',
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date(),
    esc_url( get_day_link( get_the_modified_date('Y'), get_the_modified_date('m'), get_the_modified_date('d') ) )
  );
```

*Note I changed the 3rd parameter to esc_url since it is a URL that is being generated, and that the display of the output date can be adjusted by passing in PHP date formatting options, such as  get_the_modified_date( 'm-d-Y' )*

Finally, all of this is getting stored in your $date variable as HTML, so make sure to actually echo it to the page before you're done.

Comment: I am sorry for a late reply. Works wonderful. The only thing you have missed is one closing ) after: `esc_html( get_the_modified_date()` Thanks!!!